# Set user ID at time of wp_create_user

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, user-roles, user-meta

I'd like to add a new user to the WordPress user table. The code for wp_create_user works fine but it is adding the user incrementally to the next available ID in the user table.

Instead, **I want to create the user and assign it to a particular user ID**. The user ID is already available (externally) and I want the ID entered into the WordPress database to match the external one.

```
$user_login = $username ;
$pas1 = $email_address;
$user_email = $email_address;

wp_create_user( $user_login, $pas1, $user_email );
$user = new WP_User($user_id);
$user->set_role('editor');
```

For example, I want to know how to set the known $user_id at the time of wp_create_user.

Answer (score 2):

`wp_insert_user` will not create a non-existing user with a set ID, it will return an error.

The way to do this would be to first do:

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->users, array( 'ID' => 136166 ) );

wp_insert_user( ... );
```

The code above will first create an empty user row with the set ID (it will fail hard if the ID already exists, duplicate entry for primary key ) which you can then modify using the API as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not with `wp_create_user()`. Check the source:

> ```
> 1518  function wp_create_user($username, $password, $email = '') {
> 1519          $user_login = wp_slash( $username );
> 1520          $user_email = wp_slash( $email    );
> 1521          $user_pass = $password;
> 1522  
> 1523          $userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass');
> 1524          return wp_insert_user($userdata);
> 1525  }
> ```
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1518

`wp_create_user` doesn't accept an ID argument. However, take a look at the function used at the bottom of `wp_create_user()`. [`wp_insert_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) does honor [an ID argument](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1309).

The downside is that it will overwrite an existing user with the same ID, so you will need to write the logic to handle that case.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the direction. I'll try tonight. Yes - I have code to make sure there aren't duplicates or overwriting.

Comment: wp_insert_user() won't create a user with a specific ID, only update it.